# Can't compile c program with RAWINPUTDEVICE

Tags: c, windows, compiler-errors, raw-input

I wrote this simple main.c file, to test microsoft's [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms645536(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];

int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But i can't compile it, i receive the following error:

```
gcc main.c

main.c:4:1: error: unknown type name 'RAWINPUTDEVICE'
 RAWINPUTDEVICE    Rid[1];
 ^
```

i'm using Code::Blocks, but i recieve the same error using Prompt.

I find just [this post](http://www.urbanterror.info/forums/topic/30827-42-hrawinput-error/) with an resembling error.

---

I also tryed to rename the main file to main.cpp and compile it with the g++ command, but i reciebed another error:

```
C:\Users\msouza\Desktop\Raw Input>g++ main.cpp
main.cpp:4:1: error: 'RAWINPUTDEVICE' does not name a type
 RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];
 ^
```

Comment: I think this work only in C++.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but i'm studying [this project](https://github.com/kristian/system-hook/blob/master/src/main/native/windows/SystemHook.c), which apparently uses a c file.

Comment: You should probably try to use MSVS instead of code block if you code for windows. There is a free version.

Comment: I uses Visual Studio to work with .NET. I also tryed to create a C Console Application project with MSVS, but my installation do not have this option. As i am not writing a big project in C, Code::Blocks and Prompt works well for me.

Comment: what if you include `Winuser.h`?